# Где брать токен вк?

Tags: vkontakte-api, api, token

```
https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=team&count=10&filter=owner&access_token=Ваш_токен_VK&v=5.68
```

Всем привет, где брать этот токен? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В документации всё есть https://vk.com/dev

Comment: @andreymal, есть но зачем читать книгу ради 1 фразы, я прошу прямую ссылку на создание личного токена

Comment: Сперва нужно создать приложение нужного типа, а чтобы понять, какое приложение вам нужно - нужно читать книгу

Comment: А впрочем, помимо токенов приложений бывают ещё токены сообщества, их можно получить в настройках нужного сообщества на вкладке «Работа с API» (но опять же, чтобы разобраться в функциональности и различиях — нужно читать книгу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи.
Client_id Только добавь свой:

`https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=88005553535&display=mobile&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline,wall,groups,photos&response_type=token&v=5.126&state=123456`

Answer (score 0):

Если так лень разбираться...
https://vkhost.github.io/
Вот тут можно выбрать какие права нужны и получить acess_token